# Is it possible to run a docker container without using docker?

Tags: docker

After we create a docker image, we can run it anywhere by global registry.

I am wondering if we can run it directly on a server which doesn't install docker?

New to docker, sorry if I have made any stupid mistake.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *necessarily* need to use Docker to run Docker containers - the Docker image format is an [open specification](https://github.com/docker/distribution/tree/master/docs/spec).

You will need a platform which can understand this specification - and the one provided by Docker is the reference implementation - but there are alternatives such as [Rocket](https://rocket.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Documentation/running-docker-images/).

Ultimately you will need *something* that can understand and run Docker containers, so unless your servers already have this capability you will need to install new software on them for this purpose.